# encrypt mission with condition

Tags: python, python-3.6

hay guys i got a mission to write a encrypt code with loops,strings and if/else and conditins. the condition:1.every even index of letter [like b,d,f...] change to letter that found shift step after her in lowercase.[ for example:shift=6,H become to o]
2.every odd index of index[a,c,e,...] change to letter that found shift step before her in uppercase [for example :shift=6,G become to A]
3.every "#" change to "*" and every "?" remove 
4. if "!" found in the end , then he doesn't apper in the encrypt

```
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
text = input("Please enter a sentence to encrypt:\n")
shift = int(input("Please enter the size of the shift:\n"))
newText = ""

for c in text:
    if c in alphabet:
        index = alphabet.index(c)
        index2 = (index + shift) % (len(alphabet))
        if index % 2 == 0:
            c = c.upper()
        elif index%2==1:
            c = c.lower()
        elif c=="#":
            c == "*"
        elif c=="?":
            c == ""
            newText += c

print(newText)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to start with something a bit simpler than a complete sudoku checker.

Here's a simple sudoku board that is 3x3, and has three values.

```
suduko = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [3, 1, 2]
]
```

A good way to start would be to define a couple of functions that get you a bit closer to the solution. I've made an implementation of one to get you started, and left the others...

```
def check_row(problem, row_number):
    seen = list()
    for cell in problem[row_number]:
        if cell in seen:
            return "Not ok"
        seen.append(cell)
    return "OK!"

def check_column(problem, column_number):
    # up to you
    pass

print(check_row(sudoku, 0))
print(check_row(sudoku, 1))
print(check_row(sudoku, 2))
```

Does this help you get started?

Comment: So you need to create the variable "sudoko"? How does the program get the puzzle from the user? (Not just the "side of the board", but each "line" of the solution to be checked?) You need the sudoko puzzle before you can start checking it.